# What is the correct term for separation of scripting languages?

Tags: javascript, php, html, model-view-controller

I have developed a webbased shop-system in the single page approach and by using the model view controller design pattern.

i have a few php files as the application layer, html templates and a javascript file for the presentation layer. the html files are being rendered on the client with data provided by the server as a json file.

there is no case of mixing scripting languages. so i do not have any html tags hardcoded in my application or presentation layer and vice versa, so no mixed php/javascript. not even an onclick attribute.

i can remember that my professor was a huge fan of this, so seperate all scripting languages, and i agree. i hate reviewing and fixing code where you see mixed php, html, js and css code.

is there a specific term for this 'clean scripting' approach?

Comment: It's not specifically separation of scripting languages (although that's often one side-effect). It's separation of concerns that usually drives this approach .

Comment: @Basic is correct. It's "separation of concerns".  You're separating the Data Layer, Business Layer, Presentation Layer, etc.'  A concept of model-view-controller.